# Gene location clustering

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, genetics

A friend is looking at how closely related genes cluster together on a section of DNA. In particular, he is looking at genes that code for mitochondrial phenotypes (what I will call "mitochondrial genes") vs ones that don't.

He has picked a distance, say D = 500,000 base pairs, and for each branch of each chromosome, computed -

1. The average density of genes within D base pairs of another gene.
2. The average density of genes on the entire branch.
3. The average density of mitochondrial genes with D base pairs of another mitochondrial gene.
4. The average density of mitochondrial genes on the entire branch.

The hypothesis is that mitochondrial genes cluster together more than non-mitochondrial genes do.

What statistical test is appropriate for this?